# Vue.js template loop - async axios call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm looping over an array and rendering a HTML template, this is working great. For one of the columns I need to perform an additional AJAX call using axios, so per row fetch data.

However after the AJAX call finishes, I can't get the template to update.. I've tried both passing the loop variable in as reference and attempting to return the Promise from axios.

I think I understand the basic premise of how the async calls should work, I just can't find the correct way to set this up within a Vue template/component.

E.g:

```
<tr v-for="venue in venue_results" :key="venue.id">
    <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ venue.name }}</td>
    <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ getCampsCount(venue) }} {{ venue.camps_count }}</td>
    <!-- <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ venue.active_events }}</td> -->
</tr>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            ...
            async getCampsCount(venue) {
                console.log(venue);

                let camps_count = '...';
                venue.camps_count = '...';

                let this_venue = venue;

                return axios.get(
                    route('api3.venue-courses', {venue: venue.id}),
                    {
                        params: {
                            type: 'Hol',
                            active: 1,
                        },
                    }
                )
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data.meta.total);

                    camps_count = response.data.meta.total;
                    this_venue.camps_count = response.data.meta.total;

                    return camps_count;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    camps_count = 'n/a';
                    this_venue.camps_count = 'n/a';

                    return camps_count;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // Always run
                    return camps_count;
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling data fetching operations (or any operation which mutates the component state to trigger a rerender) directly within the template like that. Just call `getCampsCount` outside of the template, like within the `created` hook or somewhere else appropriate.

Comment: You shouldn't be fetching every time the DOM is re-rendered. This is expensive and unnecessary. Instead, populate your entire `venue_results` with the asynchronous data at one go. Instead of making a single request for every row you encounter, try to bundle all of them into one request.

Comment: You're better off getting the ```camps_count``` on the server side and returning it along with the ```venue_results``` so it is a property of ```venue``` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Use a reference in the loop and access it via index.

```js
<div ref='target' />
```

```js
this.$refs.target[theIndex].innerText = 'The Value'
```

You can also create a data member, bind to that, and update in your async handler.

```
<div>{{results[venue.id]}}</div>
```

```js
this.results[venue.id] = 'The Value'
```